# Functions tag -- best usage?

Tags: discussion, tagging

At present the description for [functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) reads:

> Questions about the use and syntax of built-in Mathematica functions

Since virtually all questions fit that description I think I much better usage for the tag is for questions about **writing** *Mathematica* functions.

Please up-vote if you agree.

Comment: How does writing Mathematica functions differ from programming?

Comment: @rcollyer then consider the question: does the [tag:functions] tag serve any purpose?  (I think *maybe* writing functions is distinct enough from general programming to warrant a tag.)

Comment: In mathematics everything *is* a function, so functions as tag sounds a bit redundant. Questions about syntax should probably go by the tag syntax. What's left then? Function arguments, function options, function attributes... Perhaps we can have some two-part tags? Function-xxxx or so?

Comment: I agree with Sjoerd on this. Also, it seems to me, a number of the questions currently tagged with [function] might be better served with [functional-style]

Comment: I do agree that the tag is useless at the moment, but I don't agree on that it should be about writing _Mathematica_ functions. As all [functional-style], [syntax], [attributes] and [options] are already covered, I don't see any niche for [function] to fill up. I wonder though why isn't there any tag for *pure functions*, which are of course functions themselves, but are also very specific to _Mathematica_, are forming a rather distinct subgroup of functions and allow for nice and elegant code solutions. Are they considered part of the functional-style tag? I have zero more character to write.