# Tag for questions about constructing functions

Tags: discussion, tagging

In light of this question and its pursuant comments: [Functions tag -- best usage?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/239/121)

Please consider questions of this type:

1. [Functions vs. patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/704/121)
2. [How can I create a function with "positional" or "named" optional arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/121)
3. [Passing down arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1901/121)

I believe that these are distinct from the greater body of functional programming.

- Is there an existing tag that befits these questions, and does not excessively dilute them?
- If there is not, what is an appropriate tag?  [function-construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function-construction) ?

Comment: It seems that the focus of your example questions is more on arguments, at least the 2nd and 3rd. So wouldn't `arguments` or `function-arguments` do? I don't really like the `functions` tag as it is too broad and nondescript, although its usage (20 times so far) seems to be rather restricted.

Comment: @Sjoerd I agree that "functions" is lacking.  I would like to start retagging with something better but I don't know what.  I favor "function-construction" over "arguments" because there are questions about functions that are not only arguments (adding Attributes to an anonymous function for example).

Comment: OK, that's probably the best thing then. It fits with my earlier function-xxxx proposal.